# Write a program in C that will output the first term and the number of terms of the sequence of abundant numbers between given numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, math, numbers

An abundant number is a natural number for which the sum of its proper divisors is greater than the number itself. I have to write a program in C that will take 2 natural numbers k and m, assuming k <=m and will output the **(beginning) first term** and the length(the number of terms) of the longest sequence of successive abundant numbers between k and m, including both of these numbers. **If there exist multiple such sequences of the same length, then it has to output the smallest beginning.** If such sequence doesn't exist, then it has to output the convenient message.

Sorry for my English, I hope everything is clear. So I need help with the bolded parts. This is what I have done so far:

```
int main(void) {

    int k,m,i,j,counter=0,sum;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    scanf("%d", &m);

    for(i=k; i<=m; i++) {
        sum=0;
        for(j=1; j<i; j++) {
            if(i%j==0) sum=sum+j;
        }
        if(i<sum) {
                counter++;
                printf("%d\n", i);

        }
    }

    if(counter==0) printf("There aren't any abundant numbers!");
    else printf("%d", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs all the abundant numbers between k and m, when I only need the first term. As for this: If there exist multiple such sequences of the same length, then it has to output the smallest beginning, I don't even understand what they mean by that. How can there exist more than one such sequence between k and m?

Comment: Please show a sample input and its expected output!

Answer (score 2):

I think the assignment can be explained like this. Consider a number N.

```
N not abundant 
N+1 abundant 
N+2 abundant 
N+3 abundant 
N+4 not abundant
```

So here you have a sequence of 3 abundant numbers so you must output 3 for the length and N+1 for the number.

So you need to track the sequence length and the starting number of the sequence.

```
int current_sequence_length = 0; // Increment when you find an abundant number
                                 // Set to zero when you find a not abundant number

int current_sequence_start = 0;  // Set to the number that starts a new sequence
```

Then you need to keep track of the longest sequence so you need:

```
int longest_sequence_length = 0;

int longest_sequence_start = 0;
```

Whenever a sequence ends, you must do:

```
if (current_sequence_length > longest_sequence_length)
{
    longest_sequence_length = current_sequence_length;
    longest_sequence_start = current_sequence_start;
}
```